# currency extraction jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, operations

Clicking on any currency (e.g. `$44,721.90`) should extract by itself and return $0.

Currently is returning $NaN. I'm using ES6 `Intl.NumberFormat("en-US")` to give currency format to the numbers.

```js
var name1 = {
  name: "John",
  money: 44721.90
};
var name2 = {
  name: "Mayer",
  money: 16715.79
};

var names = [name1, name2];

function show() {
  var numFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US");
  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    $(".money").append('<div class="extract' + [i] + '"><span class="name">' + names[i].name + ' </span><span class="budget"> $' + numFormat.format(names[i].money) + '</span></div><br>');
  }
}

show();

function extraction() {
  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    //var text = $(".coin" + [i]).text();
    $(".extract" + [i]).click(function() {
      var currentCoin = $(this).find('.budget');
      var difference = $(this).find('.budget') - $(this).find('.budget');
      //var difference = (Number($(currentCoin).text().replace('$','')) - Number($(currentCoin).text().replace('$','')));
      $(currentCoin).html('$' + difference);
    })
  }
}

extraction();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="money"></div>
```

Comment: A string in the format "$16,715.79" can be implicitly converted to an number. I'd suggest storing the plain number without formatting in a data attribute which you can use for sums.

Comment: My previous comment was meant to say "cannot be implicitly converted". Also, what are you trying to do with: `$(this).find('.budget') - $(this).find('.budget');`? At the moment that doesn't seem to make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: Thanks @DBS, I appreciate if you can provide a basic fiddle example and I'll try to adapt it from there.

Comment: I can give an example, but I'm not certain exactly what the `var difference`  is supposed to be. I'll give a basic example, let me know if you can provide more detail.

Comment: Nick's solution worked for me, I appreciate your help DBS :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `var difference`, you are selecting a string with a `$` and `,`, which isn't valid to have in a number. You need to take those out of the string, something like this for that line:

```
var difference = parseFloat($(this).find('.budget').text().replace(',','').replace('$','')) - parseFloat($(this).find('.budget').text().replace(',','').replace('$',''));
```

See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/63wm1r01/4/).

Edit:

In case you decide to use something other than dollar signs you can use a regex `/[0-9\.]+/g` to match instead. I think this solution is much better actually. [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/63wm1r01/21/) a jsfiddle, I replaced the former change with a `getFloat()` function. This will work for any kind of currency.

Comment: @Syden Here, check out my update in case you change the currency.

Comment: Thanks for the update, both you and DBS provided brilliant solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `var difference = $(this).find('.budget') - $(this).find('.budget');` since those are jQuery objects, if you want to use the numeric values of these, I'd suggest you store them initially using `data-` attributes.

Example:

```js
var name1 = {
  name: "John",
  money: 44721.90
};
var name2 = {
  name: "Mayer",
  money: 16715.79
};

var names = [name1, name2];

function show() {
  var numFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US");
  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    // I've added a data-rawvalue attribute, which will store the raw value for you to use in sums
    $(".money").append('<div class="extract' + [i] + '"><span class="name">' + names[i].name + ' </span><span class="budget" data-rawvalue="' + names[i].money + '"> $' + numFormat.format(names[i].money) + '</span></div><br>');
  }
}

show();

function extraction() {
  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    $(".extract" + [i]).click(function() {
      var currentCoin = $(this).find('.budget');
      
      // Here, we use .data("rawvalue") to get the raw value we stored earlier
      var difference = $(this).find('.budget').data("rawvalue") - $(this).find('.budget').data("rawvalue");
      
      $(currentCoin).html('$' + difference);
    })
  }
}

extraction();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="money"></div>
```

Comment: Seems perfect this as well, any reason why this would be preferred in comparison to Nick's solution?

Comment: @Syden Well, this method would work even if you changed the format you display your currency, e.g. Nicks solution would fail if you were to use euros, pounds or any non-dollar currency symbol. However at the moment your output will always be 0 (x - x = 0) so potentially you could rethink how you're using it.

Comment: Excellent point on the currency switch, give me a few minutes to make a few tests and I might mark your solution as correct as well. Your help is much appreciated :)